# Is there a way to fire a function only if an event is sustained for a while

Tags: javascript, dom-events, mapbox-gl-js

I'm trying to call a function only if the user hovered over the target for a certain amount of seconds.
So it doesn't fire instantly and also doesn't just fire after a time frame but only fires if the user hovered for the entire duration of the timeframe.
If this could be done in JavaScript it would be fantastic. Thanks in advance

Comment: maybe you can have a local variable that counts up while the user is hovering and a function that listens to that variable and runs once it hits a certain number?

Comment: remember to reset back to 0 if the user mouses out before the function is triggered, and probably also after the function is triggered if you want it to be able to run again

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just set a timeout when the mouse hovers the div, and clear it when the mouse leaves the div. In this way the callback will be fired only and only if the mouse remained within the div for n seconds

```js
const el = document.querySelector('.hover-me');

let timeoutHandler = null;
el.addEventListener('mouseenter', () => {
  timeoutHandler = setTimeout(() => alert('Hovered for 2 seconds'), 2000);
});

el.addEventListener('mouseleave', () => {
  if (timeoutHandler) clearTimeout(timeoutHandler);
  timeoutHandler = null;
});
```

```css
div.hover-me {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  background-color: lightblue;
}
```

```html
<div class="hover-me">Hover me</div>
```